# sql sub query difficulties

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

At the moment I am revising my sql. I wish to perform a query in a table of items, where I would like to get the cheapest sweets.

```
select min(cost)
from items
where name like '%sweets%' and seller_id
in (    
    select seller_id
    from items
    where name like '%sweets%')
```

The above result, returns the cheapest price.

Problem:

I would like to display the name of the sweets, for example it may be chocolate sweets or strawberry sweets, etc. but if i change the first line of the query to select name, min(cost) the following error is produced:

```
Column 'items.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained 
in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Now I am viewing MYSQL tutorials but I am working on sql server. It worked fine in the tutorial but not in my case

Comment: MySQL allows this but sql-server does not.  But it's okay, since you shouldn't be doing it in MySQL anyway.

Comment: What should be the answer for following case. asweet 30 seller1, bsweet 30 seller2, abc 20 seller3, dsweet 40 seller4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you all fields in the cheapest row(s), not just cost:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE
    name LIKE '%sweets%'
    AND cost = (SELECT MIN(cost) FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%sweets%')
```

BTW, a suffix search `LIKE %something` will cause a full table scan (and correspondingly poor performance).

Comment: thank you this worked well. so just for curiosity what would you suggest to have better performence?

Comment: Search conditions such as `= 'something'` ("equi-search") or `LIKE 'something%'` (prefix-search) can be sped-up by B-tree indexes. Take a look at [Indexing SQL LIKE Filters](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning). So the best thing you can do for your performance is to limit yourself to equi- and prefix-searches. If you absolutely **must** search on suffix, indexing a computed column (that is reverse of original column) might help. If you need infix-search, there is essentially no help, not even from a full-text index in general case.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to lowest cost item, then order by cost and select the first row.

```
Select top 1 name, cost
from items
where name like '%sweets%'
order by cost desc
```

Comment: Doesn't this only return a single row regardless of how many items have a name like "sweet"?  Although I may be misunderstanding the OP, which isn't very clear.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this will only return 1 row. But then I may not be understanding the OP either. To returns multiples update the query to `select top 10...`

Answer (score 3):

This Should work.

```
select *
from items
where name like '%sweets%' and cost
in (    
    select min(cost)
    from items
    where name like '%sweets%')
```

Comment: May need a top 1 on the outer select, in the case of ties in cost.

Comment: Well, I hoped we should show both in that case, otherwise we need top 1.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a subquery to do this.  You can just order the table by price:

```
select top 10 * 
from items 
where name like '%sweets%'
order by price asc
```

This will get you the 10 cheapest items that match `%sweets`.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing describes what you need to do--add a `GROUP BY` clause to your query.  Additionally, your subquery is unnecessary as far as I can tell.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    i.[name],
    MIN(i.[cost])
FROM [items] i
WHERE i.name LIKE '%sweet%'
GROUP BY i.[name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `group by items.name` at the bottom

Comment: that simply gives me the result of the inner query :/